# Automorphic forms and coherent cohomology

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, automorphic-forms, galois-representations

Why is it (and what does it mean) that automorphic forms do not contribute in the coherent cohomology of Siegel modular varieties parametrizing abelian varieties of dimension $d>2$ (see section 7 of the [thesis](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-02940906/document) of Nguyen or section 1.4.1 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.09269.pdf) of Boxer, Calegari, Gee, and Pilloni)?

Apparently this comes from the fact that the Hodge-Tate weight of the associated motive is neither regular nor weakly regular, i.e. the same number appears more than twice in the Hodge-Tate weights, but why does this mean that we cannot find them in the coherent cohomology? Apparently this is also true for the Betti cohomology of the associated locally symmetric space. Does the theorem of Franke (generalization of Eichler-Shimura) have anything to say about this?

Comment: The question as written doesn't make sense (or is wrong...): the correct statement is that the motive of an abelian variety of dimension $>2$ with endomorphism ring the integers does not occur in the (motive associated to) the coherent cohomology of (automorphic vector bundles on) a Shimura variety.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for getting it wrong. I would be happy to edit the question, but could you elaborate more or give me some references to learn more about this?

Comment: @naf If you know the correct statement then do you also know an answer? It might be a bit more constructive to maybe expand on this a bit more :-)

Comment: @Tim: The explanation in the paper of BGGP is fairly detailed and seems quite clear to me. What I said corresponds to the statement in brackets beginning with "Another..." in the second paragraph there. If there is something specific you do not understand you should ask a more focused question.

Comment: @naf I am neither a number theorist nor an algebraic geometer, but perhaps the OP would find it useful to see an expanded version of the statement "Another way to see this..." that you refer to. I don't know if "computing the possible infinitesimal characters" is supposed to be a standard procedure in this setting, but perhaps an outline of how one does this for a toy example could be helpful for the OP?

Comment: (Alternatively, is there a representation-theoretic explanation of why certain representations are not contained in the discrete series for the relevant group, without going through Hodge-Tate weights?)

Comment: @YemonChoi: Coherent cohomology actually corresponds to non-degenerate limits of discrete series. Without knowing anything about what the OP is willing to assume, it is not possible (for me) to write a short answer which would also be useful.

Comment: @naf: I think I understand now why the motives of abelian varieties of dimension d>2 cannot come from the coherent cohomology of a Shimura variety: The former is never regular, since HT weights are d 1's and d 0's. The latter however are required to be regular. Could you give me a reference for coherent cohomology that discusses this?

Comment: I also agree that a short answer with some reference could be useful, not only for the OP but for other people interested in this question as well. Even if it is not perfect, it would be better than nothing.

Comment: A good reference for coherent cohomology of Shimura varieties is the paper of Michael Harris, cited as [Har90b] in the BCGP paper. In particular, Proposition 4.3.2 there gives a formula for the infinitesimal character associated to the coherent cohomology of an automorphic vector bundle. You might also find the paper of Gross cited as [Gro16] in BCGM useful: it explains the role played by the endomorphism ring of the abelian variety.